# Algo Issue - Find a group of item in a list

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Here is what I'm trying to do :

I have 2 lists.

List 1 : 00F0001,00F0002,00F0003,00F0004,00F0005,00F0006,00F0007,00F0008,00F0009,00F0010

List 2 : 00F0006,00F0007,00F0008 (this list is generate by the 1st item($debut) and the last one($fin))

What i want to do is :

return me true if the "List 2" is in the "List 1", just that.

So I tried with 2 for but I get blocked :/

My code :

```
    $id = substr($debut,0,4);
    echo '</br>id : '.$id; /* = 00F0*/

    $Start = substr($debut,4,25);
    $End = substr($fin,4,25);
    $range = $End - $Start +1;

    echo '</br>Range : '.$range; /* = 3 with the example I gave*/

    for ($i = 0;$i < $range;$i++){
        $indice2 = $Start + $i;
        $Num_Serie = str_pad($indice2, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $Num_Serie_Final[$i] = $id.''.$Num_Serie;
    }
    $ArrayNS = $Num_Serie_Final;
$i_W = 0;
while(($produit = $reponse->fetch())AND($check3 == "false")){

    $ArrayProduit[$i_W] = $produit[1];
    $i_W++;
    }

for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < $i_W; $i2++){
    for ($i3 = 0; $i3 < $range; $i3++){
        if ($ArrayNS[$i2] == $ArrayProduit[$i3]){
          .... ???? .....
        }
    }
}
```

The 1st "for" is to build my "List 2".
The "while" loop is to generate my "List 1"

Then i did a double "for" loop but its here where I lock :/

**EDIT**

I tried something for the one interested :

```
    for ($i3 = 0; $i3 < $range; $i3++){
    for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < $i_W; $i2++){
        if ($ArrayNS[$i3] == $ArrayProduit[$i2]){
            for ($indice=0; $indice < $range; $indice++){
                if ($ArrayNS[$indice] == $ArrayProduit[$i2+$indice]){
                    $ok = true;
                    echo '$ArrayNS[$indice] : '.$ArrayNS[$indice].'   ==   $ArrayProduit[$i2+$indice] : '.$ArrayProduit[$i2+$indice].'</br>';
                }
                else {
                    $ok = false;
                    $id_erreur = $ArrayNS[$indice];
                    echo 'Fail with : '.$ArrayNS[$indice].'   !==   '.$ArrayProduit[$i2+$indice].'</br>';
                }
            }
            if ($ok) {
                echo 'Success !!!';
                return ($ok);
            }
            else {
                echo 'Fail !!!';
                return ($id_erreur);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Probably not the best way to do it but it works ^^

Comment: Instead of checking for equality, check for inequality and break out of the inner loop if there's no match. Use a flag to determine whether you broke out or finished the inner loop. Within outer loop, after inner loop, check flag for success.

Answer (score 1):

I chose js for console testability, but the algorithm is the same in php.

This one returns an index, but you just have to check if your index is different from `-1` to tell if it has been found or not.

The idea is to loop through each element of the haystack (`l1` here) and if the current element matches the first element of our needle (`l2`) then we start to loop from the current haystack index (`i`) to the end of our needle index (`i + j`), but if any of these elements doesn't match (at the first occurrence) we skip to the next value of the haystack (`l1`) and try again. If we did not fail (`failedMatch` flag) then return the index of the subsequence (`l2` in `l1` start position).

If the subsequence doesn't appear in the haystack we return `-1` by convention.

This is a left to right approach so it will only match the first occurrence of the subsequence, and if it appears more than once, you won't know.

```
var l1 = [1,2,3,3,4,5,6],
    l2 = [3,4,5];

function subsequenceIndex(l1 /* haystack */, l2 /* needle */) {
    var startIndex = -1,
        failedMatch;

    for (var i = 0; i < l1.length; i++) {
        failedMatch = false;
        if (l1[i] === l2[0]) {

            for (var j = 1; j < l2.length; j++) {

                // check first that l1[i + j] is set
                if (l1[i + j] !== undefined && l2[j] !== l1[i + j]) {
                    failedMatch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!failedMatch) {
                startIndex = i;
            }

        }
        if (startIndex !== -1) {
            return startIndex;
        }
     }

    return startIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for taking time and post a solution, I tried myself something else, for the moment its working perfectly, but if it doesn't work later. I will go with your algo ;)